# Code inside For Loop not executed

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro:

```
Sub CalculateCQ()
    'Part I: copy sample names
    Dim SourceExcel As String, CQVals(1 To 8) As Single, RowNum As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    SourceExcel = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Workbooks.Open (SourceExcel)
    Worksheets("Samples").Activate

    Range("B2:B13").Copy
    Windows("testbook.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Part II: copy CQ IR values
    For i = 1 To i = 12 Step 1
        Windows(SourceExcel).Activate
        Worksheets("CQ").Activate

        MsgBox "Running thought sample"
        For j = 1 To j = 8 Step 1
            RowNum = 2 + 25 * (i - 1) + 3 * (j - 1)

            If Cells(RowNum, 5).Value = "inf" Or Cells(RowNum, 5).Value = "N/A" Then
                CQVals(j) = 10000.1
            Else
                CQVals(j) = Val(Cells(RowNum, 5).Value)
            End If
            MsgBox CQVals(j)
        Next j

        Windows("testbook.xlsx").Activate
        'Cells((i + 2), 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(CQVals)
        Cells((i + 2), 2).Value = "Test"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Part I works as expacted, however part II does not seem to be executed at all. When trying to narrow the problem down with `MsgBox`, I found nothing inside the first for loop (`For i = 1 To i = 12 Step 1`) does not get executed.

- `"testbook.xlsx"` is the macro workbook

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question as it is a typo (syntax error).

Comment: Please do. It works fine now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the VBA Editor accepts this as valid syntax. What happens in the background is that the `i = 12` evaluates as `false` (i is 0 at that moment), false is represented as 0 (true = -1) and so the for loop is `from i = 1 to 0` and therefore never executed.

Comment: Reading your comment was alot of @FunThomas

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a `for` loop is

```
For i = 1 To 12 Step 1
For j = 1 To 8 Step 1
```

Note that `Step 1` is the default, so it is not necessary.